# Função para delay / atrasar abertura de uma div

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

Tenho uma div flutuante com um botão 'fechar', que faz o hidden / visible.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function controlaLayer(layerover) 
{ 
if( document.getElementById(layerover).style.visibility == "hidden" ) 
{ 
    document.getElementById(layerover).style.visibility = "visible"; 
} else { 
    document.getElementById(layerover).style.visibility = "hidden"; 
} 
}
</script>

<div id="1">
<div id="2">
<div id="3">

<div id="layerover">
<a href="#" onmouseover="controlaLayer('layerover')"><b>X</b></a>
<img></img>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Gostaria que essa div carregasse apenas após 2 segundos que o usuário entre na página. lí um pouco sobre setTimeout mas vi que cria um loop e eu de abrir a div só um vez.

Sou leigo em JS, conto com vocês.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade voce precisa exatamente do `setTimeout`, esse que cria um loop se chama `setInterval()`, que como o nome ja diz vai executar o codigo a cada X tempo, voltando para o seu caso ficaria assim:

Só fiquei na duvida de qual div abrir.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function controlaLayer(layerover) 
    { 
        if( document.getElementById(layerover).style.visibility == "hidden" ) 
        { 
            document.getElementById(layerover).style.visibility = "visible"; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById(layerover).style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        } 
    }

    //vai executar quando o doom estiver pronto para ser manipulado
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            //aqui é o codigo que vai ser executado depois do tempo determinado no segundo parametro
            controlaLayer('layerover');
        }, 2000);// <-- o tempo que vai levar ate a funcao ser executada, em milisegundos
    });
</script>

<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
        <div id="3">
            <div id="layerover">
                <a href="#" onmouseover="controlaLayer('layerover')"><b>X</b></a>
                <img></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```